# Why is this simple factorial code not working?

Tags: python

Why doesnt it print the factorial?

```
def fac(n):
    result = 1
    while n != 1:
        result = result * n
        n = n-1
    print(result)

print(fac(4))
```

Comment: You are printing, not returning, the final result.

Comment: @chepner is right. But that should still print the factorial somewhere.

Comment: @Perplexabot it does. It prints 24 and then None

Comment: def fac(n):
    result = 1
    while n != 1:
        result = result * n
        n = n-1
    return result

print(fac(4))

Comment: so when you run the code it prints something? in my case the code runs successfully but doesnt print anything

Answer (score 2):

You are printing, not returning, the final result

```
def fac(n):
    result = 1
    while n != 1:
        result = result * n
        n = n-1
    return result

print(fac(4))
```